# QuickFIXJ Logon Issue

Tags: java, quickfix, fix-protocol, financial, hft

Having issues w/QuickFixJ. The issue is that I can't correctly send a logon message. Additionally, I'm having a hard-time understanding how to setup the flow of messages. I'm not trying to execute trades, just retrieve market data.

The error:

```
20140123-22:55:56: No responder, not sending message:
```

Here's all my details:

Incoming:
cat incoming/*

```
8=FIXT.1.19=11035=A34=149=REDACTED-MD52=20140123-22:55:56.37256=NDXMD98=0108=30141=Y553=REDACTED100554=REDACTED1137=910=231?220140123-22:55:56.470
```

Outgoing:

```
20140123-22:55:50: Session FIXT.1.1:REDACTED-MD->NDXMD schedule is weekly, SUN 00:00:00-UTC - FRI 00:00:00-UTC
20140123-22:55:50: Created session: FIXT.1.1:REDACTED-MD->NDXMD
20140123-22:55:53: Initiated logon request
20140123-22:55:56: No responder, not sending message: 8=FIXT.1.19=11035=A34=149=REDACTED-MD52=20140123-22:55:56.37256=NDXMD98=0108=30141=Y553=REDACTED100554=REDACTED1137=910=231
8=FIXT.1.19=8135=A34=149=REDACTED-MD52=20140123-22:55:52.64356=NDXMD98=0108=30141=Y1137=910=114
8=FIXT.1.19=8335=549=NDXMD56=REDACTED-MD52=20140123-22:55:53.75134=158=Missing field. Type 55310=054
8=FIXT.1.19=11035=A34=149=REDACTED-MD52=20140123-22:55:56.37256=NDXMD98=0108=30141=Y553=REDACTED100554=REDACTED1137=910=231
```

And my stdout is:
J

```
an 23, 2014 10:55:37 PM REDACTED.REDACTEDMain main
INFO: REDACTED startup
Jan 23, 2014 10:55:49 PM quickfix.SessionSchedule <init>
INFO: [FIXT.1.1:REDACTEDB-MD->NDXMD] weekly, SUN 00:00:00-UTC - FRI 00:00:00-UTC
Successfully called onCreate for sessionId : FIXT.1.1:REDACTEDB-MD->NDXMD
Jan 23, 2014 10:55:50 PM quickfix.mina.NetworkingOptions logOption
INFO: Socket option: SocketTcpNoDelay=true
Jan 23, 2014 10:55:50 PM quickfix.mina.NetworkingOptions logOption
INFO: Socket option: SocketSynchronousWrites=false
Jan 23, 2014 10:55:50 PM quickfix.mina.NetworkingOptions logOption
INFO: Socket option: SocketSynchronousWriteTimeout=30000
Jan 23, 2014 10:55:51 PM quickfix.mina.initiator.IoSessionInitiator <init>
INFO: [FIXT.1.1:REDACTEDB-MD->NDXMD] [web-fix.REDACTED.com/194.107.REDACTED:7170]
Jan 23, 2014 10:55:51 PM quickfix.mina.SessionConnector startSessionTimer
INFO: SessionTimer started
Sleeping for start() ....
Jan 23, 2014 10:55:51 PM quickfix.mina.initiator.InitiatorIoHandler sessionCreated
INFO: MINA session created for FIXT.1.1:REDACTEDB-MD->NDXMD: local=/10.215.87.15:34197, class org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketSessionImpl, remote=web-fix.REDACTED.com/194.107.REDACTED:7170
Inside toAdmin
Message: 8=FIXT.1.19=8135=A34=149=REDACTEDB-MD52=20140123-22:55:52.64356=NDXMD98=0108=30141=Y1137=910=114
XML: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<message>
<header>
<field tag="8"><![CDATA[FIXT.1.1]]></field>
<field tag="9"><![CDATA[81]]></field>
<field tag="34"><![CDATA[1]]></field>
<field tag="35"><![CDATA[A]]></field>
<field tag="49"><![CDATA[REDACTEDB-MD]]></field>
<field tag="52"><![CDATA[20140123-22:55:52.643]]></field>
<field tag="56"><![CDATA[NDXMD]]></field>
</header>
<body>
<field tag="98"><![CDATA[0]]></field>
<field tag="108"><![CDATA[30]]></field>
<field tag="141"><![CDATA[Y]]></field>
<field tag="1137"><![CDATA[9]]></field>
</body>
<trailer>
<field tag="10"><![CDATA[114]]></field>
</trailer>
</message>

Header: quickfix.fixt11.Message$Header@10f268de
Trailer: quickfix.Message$Trailer@1ac2cf83
Jan 23, 2014 10:55:53 PM quickfix.mina.AbstractIoHandler messageReceived
SEVERE: Invalid message: Can't determine ApplVerID for message
Jan 23, 2014 10:55:53 PM quickfix.Session disconnect
INFO: [FIXT.1.1:REDACTEDB-MD->NDXMD] Disconnecting: IO Session closed
Successfully logged out for sessionId : FIXT.1.1:REDACTEDB-MD->NDXMD
Inside toAdmin
Message: 8=FIXT.1.19=11035=A34=249=REDACTEDB-MD52=20140123-22:55:56.37256=NDXMD98=0108=30141=Y553=REDACTED100554=REDACTED1137=910=232
XML: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<message>
<header>
<field tag="8"><![CDATA[FIXT.1.1]]></field>
<field tag="9"><![CDATA[110]]></field>
<field tag="34"><![CDATA[2]]></field>
<field tag="35"><![CDATA[A]]></field>
<field tag="49"><![CDATA[REDACTEDB-MD]]></field>
<field tag="52"><![CDATA[20140123-22:55:56.372]]></field>
<field tag="56"><![CDATA[NDXMD]]></field>
</header>
<body>
<field tag="98"><![CDATA[0]]></field>
<field tag="108"><![CDATA[30]]></field>
<field tag="141"><![CDATA[Y]]></field>
<field tag="553"><![CDATA[REDACTED100]]></field>
<field tag="554"><![CDATA[REDACTED]]></field>
<field tag="1137"><![CDATA[9]]></field>
</body>
<trailer>
<field tag="10"><![CDATA[232]]></field>
</trailer>
</message>

Header: quickfix.fixt11.Message$Header@49f8d077
Trailer: quickfix.Message$Trailer@6e3e5a91
Logon Message Sent : false
```

And my source in question is:
MAIN:

```
 try {
        Application app = new AFIX();
        SessionSettings settings          = new SessionSettings("sessionSettings.txt");
        FileStoreFactory fileStoreFactory = new FileStoreFactory(settings);
        FileLogFactory logFactory         = new FileLogFactory(settings);
        MessageFactory messageFactory     = new DefaultMessageFactory();
        SocketInitiator socketInitiator   = new SocketInitiator(app,
                fileStoreFactory, settings, logFactory, messageFactory);
        socketInitiator.start();
        try {
            System.out.println("Sleeping for start() ....");
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SessionID sessionId = socketInitiator.getSessions().get(0);
        AFIX.sendLogonRequest(sessionId);

        int i = 0;
        do {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println(socketInitiator.isLoggedOn());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            i++;
        } while ((!socketInitiator.isLoggedOn()) && (i < 25));

    } catch (ConfigError e) {
```

...
...
...

```
 public static void sendLogonRequest(SessionID sessionId)
        throws SessionNotFound {

    quickfix.fixt11.Logon logon = new quickfix.fixt11.Logon();
    quickfix.Message.Header header = logon.getHeader();

    header.setField(new quickfix.field.BeginString("FIXT.1.1"));
    header.setField(new quickfix.field.MsgType("A"));

    Properties p = loadProperties();
    logon.set(new quickfix.field.Username(p.getProperty("username")));
    logon.set(new quickfix.field.Password(p.getProperty("password")));

    logon.set(new quickfix.field.HeartBtInt(30));
    logon.set(new quickfix.field.ResetSeqNumFlag(true));
    logon.set(new quickfix.field.DefaultApplVerID("9"));
    logon.set(new quickfix.field.EncryptMethod(0));

    boolean sent = Session.sendToTarget(logon, sessionId);
    System.out.println("Logon Message Sent : " + sent);
}
```

And finally my settings:

cat sessionSettings.txt

```
[DEFAULT]# Settings which apply to all the Sessions.
ConnectionType=initiator
LogonTimeout=30
ReconnectInterval=30
UseDataDictionary=Y
ResetOnLogon=Y
FileStorePath=incoming
FileLogPath=outgoing

[SESSION]# Settings specifically for one session
BeginString=FIXT.1.1 
DefaultApplVerID=9
AppDataDictionary=FIX50.xml
SenderCompID=REDACTED-MD
TargetCompID=NDXMD
StartDay=sunday
EndDay=friday
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
HeartBtInt=30
CheckLatency=N
MaxLatency=240
SocketConnectPort=7170
SocketConnectHost=web-fix.REDACTED.com

UseDataDictionary=Y
DataDictionary=lib/quickfixj-all-1.5.3.jar!/FIX50SP2.xml
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

Look at the [example OrderMatch app](http://sourceforge.net/p/quickfixj/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/examples/src/main/java/quickfix/examples/ordermatch/Main.java).

(It's an acceptor, not an initiator, but it doesn't really matter.)

You'll notice that it doesn't manually create a Logon message and send it.  The engine does that automatically upon `initiator.start` (or `acceptor.start`).  (See in your log: "*No responder, not sending message*" -- that's your manual logon line trying to send before the engine has done its proper logon).

Basically, take all that code between `socketInitiator.start();` and the end of the block and **delete the heck out of it**.  Just put in some kind of sleep action (like a wait-for-console-input or something) instead.

You may still have other issues, but that's the one I'm seeing now.

Comment: Grant -- thanks, ok trying that now. Still have to determine how to send my credentials in the logon message though.

Comment: [See here](http://www.quickfixj.org/confluence/display/qfj/User+FAQ) for how to add username/password to logon message.

Comment: Grant -- tried that and still no dice. I'm still researching options and source code ... so we'll see.

Comment: Updated link to that username/password logon documentation: https://www.quickfixj.org/wiki/display/qfj/User+FAQ

Answer (score 3):

To send credentials you want to override the toAdmin method that is inherited from Application.
First check the MsgType which is held in the header, make sure its a logon message.  Then you can add the relevant fields to the message at that point.  The quickfix engine will then send the message with everything you need it in.

If you are waiting to do something before after the logon, then implement the MessageCracker interface.

Override the fromApp method from Application and call crack on the msg.  You will then override the onLogon method form MessageCracker and you can run the rest of you code from that point as you will know that you are logged on.

Answer (score 1):

Applicable for FIXT.1.1

To Solve:
Can't determine ApplVerID for message

In your toAdmin() method add below line,
**Session.lookupSession(sessionId).setTargetDefaultApplicationVersionID(new ApplVerID("9"));**

This will solve the problem and the logout message will be passed to fromAdmin() method